# Binding a function to a key in python. Working with GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, keyboard-events

I'm working on a project at the moment and I need to bind the keys control
command
left arrow 
right arrow

each to a different function. I've figured out how to bind the entire key board to functions. But I can't figure out how to do it for the individual keys. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use Tkinter. Is there an alternative to using that to bind individual keys?

This is what I've done to bind the entire keyboard.

```
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class KeyboardWidget(QWidget):
    keyPressed = pyqtSignal(str)
    def keyPressEvent(self,keyEvent):
        self.keyPressed.emit(keyEvent.text())
```

and then I import that code into my main file and call on a function that is connected to any key.

If you have any way of making it so that I can click on individual keys that would be amazing!

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
>
> This event handler, for event event, can be reimplemented in a subclass to receive key press events for the widget.

---

> int QKeyEvent::key() const
>
> Returns the code of the key that was pressed or released.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(700, 400)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 200
        self.show()

    def up(self):
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left: 
            self.x -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x += 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:    
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:  
            self.y += 5
        self.up()    

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.x <= -45:
            self.x = 725
        elif self.x >= 725:
            self.x = -45
        if self.y <= -25:
            self.y = 415
        elif self.y >= 415:
            self.y = -25
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(150, 75, 0))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 50, 20)
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x + 10, self.y - 10, 30, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]